# Dask Dataframe from parquet files: OSError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Invalid data

Tags: dask, parquet, pyarrow, dask-dataframe

I'm generating a Dask dataframe to be used downstream in a clustering algorithm supplied by dask-ml. In a previous step in my pipeline I read a dataframe from disk using the `dask.dataframe.read_parquet`, apply a transformation to add columns using `map_partitions`, and then write the resulting dataframe back to disk using `dask.dataframe.to_parquet`. The issue occurs when the resulting dataframe gets read again and `compute()` is called.

Running the following code:

```
# First step: make the Dask dataframe
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(partition_func)  # in this case, perform a df.apply, then pandas.concat with the original
ddf_output_path = pathlib.Path("./data/")  # Some directory
ddf_output_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
dask.dataframe.to_parquet(ddf, ddf_output_path)  # Succeeds

# Second step: attempt to read and compute on the Dask dataframe
ddf = dask.dataframe.read_parquet(ddf_output_path)
print(ddf.columns)  # Produces the correct output
print(ddf.shape[0].compute())  # <-- fails here, for example
```

Produces the following traceback:

```
 File "/home/ec2-user/pycharm_remote/pipeline/perform_clustering.py", line 32, in run
    print(ddf.shape[0].compute())
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 167, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 452, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 84, in get
    **kwargs
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 486, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 316, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 222, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 121, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py", line 276, in read_parquet_part
    dfs = [func(fs, rg, columns.copy(), index, **kwargs) for rg in part]
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py", line 276, in <listcomp>
    dfs = [func(fs, rg, columns.copy(), index, **kwargs) for rg in part]
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py", line 758, in read_partition
    piece, columns, partitions, **kwargs
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py", line 817, in _parquet_piece_as_arrow
    **kwargs.get("read", {}),
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet.py", line 719, in read
    table = reader.read_row_group(self.row_group, **options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/virtualenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet.py", line 272, in read_row_group
    use_threads=use_threads)
  File "pyarrow/_parquet.pyx", line 1080, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetReader.read_row_group
  File "pyarrow/_parquet.pyx", line 1099, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetReader.read_row_groups
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 99, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
OSError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Invalid data
Deserializing page header failed.
```

The environment is Amazon Linux 2, Python 3.7.9, with dask == 2.30.0, pyarrow == 2.0.0, pandas == 1.1.5, numpy == 1.19.4. The dask dataframe consists of 404 columns and is read from approximately 14,000 parquet files (partitions). Four of the columns contain items of type `object` (three hold strings, one holds a nested list of strings), while the remaining 400 contain type `float64`.

Comment: One source of the problem could be that the pandas dataframes generated by the call to map_partitions had column names of type other than string (integers from 0 to 399). I got this UserWarning from pyarrow: `The DataFrame has column names of mixed type. They will be converted to strings and not roundtrip correctly.`

Comment: Correcting the column names didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You may want to try with pyarrow < 2 for now

Comment: If you manually read a single file, eg with pandas (`pd.read_parquet("path/to/single/file.parquet")`. Does it then give the same error?